# How to Change PHPStorm or IntelliJ Color (Whole IDE, not just color scheme)?

Tags: intellij-idea, ide, phpstorm

I See only 2 Options here: Default and Dracula.

[image]

How can i change Whole IDE (not just color scheme) in to any Colors like a Blue?

Comment: Have you tried http://phpstorm-themes.com/content/help and http://www.ideacolorthemes.org/help/?

Comment: Yes... http://phpstorm-themes.com/  Whole IDE , not just color scheme...

Comment: We can't help you if you don't explain what you tried, what error you had,etc.

Comment: We? you can't help me! because you don't understand my Question! How to Change PHPStorm or IntelliJ Color (Whole IDE, not just color scheme)? Your Link is only how to change a scheme-color...

Comment: Ah, sorry, I thought these were themes for the entire IDE. I can't find a downloadable IDE theme, it seems that you can only choose `Default` or `Darcula`.

Comment: I'm Sure that's Possible ;) Show here, i just scored photo whit my Smartphone from TV (Silicon Valley, Richard Hendrix IntelliJ Idea), IDE and scheme are Complete Blue! http://abload.de/image.php?img=20141211_072646s5f91.jpg

Comment: You cannot -- I mean: there is no GUI options for that. Unless you hack/create your own GUI theme (a.k.a. Look & Feel): all such colors are hard coded inside them.

Comment: That is really too bad. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: It's possible that things will change in a future -- I know that some guy(s) is(are) working on having customizable Darcula theme (at least some aspects of it) -- not sure how good the progress is and when it will be available (if at all) -- I just remember seeing some screenshots where some colors were heavily altered as compared to standard Darcula. Will see...

Answer (score 0):

IDE Themes are just java Look&Feels. Implementing a new L&F is a tough task... Note that it's technically possible to install any third-party L&F into JVM and use it in PHPStorm ( see https://weblogs.java.net/blog/kirillcool/archive/2005/08/intellij_idea_5.html for instructions), but it will most likely look ugly and break the UI in many places.
You can also try Color IDE plugin (https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7055?pr=webstorm).
see also https://laracasts.com/series/how-to-be-awesome-in-phpstorm/, episode 2 and 3